# Unity Render Shadow Only 1 Main Camera by using OnPreRender(), OnPostRender()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, shadow

I have 4 Cameras. 1 Main Camera and 3 Sub Cameras.

I don't want to render shadow in 3 Sub Cameras, so I'm attaching the code below to 3 sub Camera.

```
// https://answers.unity.com/questions/1219726/make-shadows-disappear.html

private void OnPreRender()
{
    shadowDisatance = QualitySettings.shadowDistance;
    QualitySettings.shadowDistance = 0;
}

private void OnPostRender()
{
    QualitySettings.shadowDistance = shadowDisatance;
}
```

It works fine, but I just don't want to attach this script to 3 Sub Cameras. Instead, I want to make a script and attach it to 1 Main camera only.

Surely, the purpose of this code below is to make Main camera only render shadow.

```
private void OnPreRender()
{
    QualitySettings.shadowDistance = 40;
}

private void OnPostRender()
{
    QualitySettings.shadowDistance = 0;
}
```

But it makes Main Camera do not render shadow. It just makes every shadowDistance 0.

Please help.

Comment: just a sidenode you could instead also simply set [`QualitySettings.shadows = ShadowQuality.Disable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-shadows.html) in the subcameras and do nothing for the main camera instead of dealing with distances

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. but the problem is that I just don't want to attach a script to 3 Sub Cameras...

Comment: well .. why not?

Comment: Actually, I have a more 10 Sub Cameras... and my 'Boss' suggest me that we just can manipulate one Main Camera only.

Comment: well in your question you spoke about 3 ... and maybe your 'Boss' has to be more flexible then ;) Or look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why but if you do not want to attach anything on the subcameras you could instead use [`Camera.onPreRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-onPreRender.html) and [`Camera.onPostRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-onPostRender.html) and let it do the thing for every camera except the mainCamera.

And as said I would rather change [`QualitySettings.shadows`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-shadows.html) instead of `shadowDistance` but that's up to you obviously.

Something like this

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class DisableSubCamShadows : MonoBehaviour
{
    // either drag this in via the inspector
    public Camera mainCamera;

    private ShadowQuality _originalShadowSettings

    // or get it on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        // mainCamera will be the one attached to this object
        mainCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        // store original shadow settings
        _originalShadowSettings = QualitySettings.shadows;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // register the callbacks when enabling object
        Camera.onPreRender += MyPreRender;
        Camera.onPostRender += MyPostRender;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // remove the callbacks when disabling object
        Camera.onPreRender -= MyPreRender;
        Camera.onPostRender -= MyPostRender;
    }

    // callback before ANY camera starts rendering
    private void MyPreRender(Camera cam)
    {
        // if mainCamera set to originalShadowSettings 
        // could also simply return but just to be sure
        //
        // for other camera disable shadows
        QualitySettings.shadows = cam == mainCamera ? originalShadowSettings : ShadowQuality.Disable;   
    }

    // callback after ANY camera finishes rendering
    private void MyPostRenderer(Camera cam)
    {
        // restore shadow settings
        QualitySettings.shadows = originalShadowSettings;
    }
}
```

attach this to the MainCamera

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. I really appreciate it.